# primefaces p:calendar component pattern

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-1.2

i just got a simple query. i am using **p:calendar** in my project. it works fine with `pattern="HH:mm"`, but if i change it to `pattern="KK:mm"` it only displays the inputtext with the current time.

this works fine

```
<p:calendar id="p6" value="#{testBean.date}" pattern="HH:mm"   styleClass="calStyle" timeOnly="true" >
```

but this doesnt.

```
   <p:calendar id="p6" value="#{testBean.date}" pattern="kk:mm"   styleClass="calStyle" timeOnly="true" >
```

i wanted time from 01:00 to 24:59, thus i am using "kk:mm" pattern.
any guidence is highly appreciated.

Thanks:)

Comment: Have you tried pattern="k:mm"?  I think you only need one `k` since it will provide the Hour of the Day

Comment: @gtgaxiola i just tried it. it isnt working.

Answer (score 2):

I think reason is Primefaces using [Jquery](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#dates) date patterns. You can have an overview at [ConvertPattern](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/calendar/CalendarUtils.java?r=6605) method. HH should already provide 24h and hh 12h.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links.i know HH would give default 24h format starting from 00:00 to 23:59, but i want my time like this format 01:00 to 24:59, which is acheived using 'kk:mm' pattern in java. do u by any chance have any idea how would this be achieved in jquery as PF implements jquery.

Comment: maybe instead you can try <f:convertDateTime type="time" pattern="kk:mm" /> in calendar tag

Comment: What kind of sorcery is 01:00 to 24:59?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A non-zero based indexing :P

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza haha, right?..even i lol'd when i saw the requirement. its actually for a time scheduler app. there might be an event which starts at midnight and ends at midnight on the same day. :)